# php mysql query issue

Tags: sql, mysql

here's my table:

[image]

and I want get the customers which have some values of `for/category` fields which is comma separated..

I am trying something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `for` LIKE ('%AMC PHD & WWS%' OR '%Rostfrei%' OR '%Thermopac%')
```

but its giving empty result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RedFilter's SQL is correct, but you should also know that "for" is a MySQL reserved word. You should avoid using it as a column name, or wrap it in backticks when you use it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE `for` LIKE '%AMC PHD & WWS%'
    OR `for` LIKE '%Rostfrei%'
    OR `for` LIKE '%Thermopac%';
```

The alternative, typing the column name once is:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE `for` REGEXP 'AMC PHD \& WWS|Rostfrei|Thermopac';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE for LIKE '%AMC PHD & WWS%'
    or for LIKE '%Rostfrei%'
    or for LIKE '%Thermopac%'
```

Comment: it seems to be working.. but is there any way so that I don't have to write field name again and again..?